# Database program for statistics about mistakes

Tags: analysis, statistics, database

I wonder if there is an application that will help with statistics for my own games. Of course - there are applications (eg. Scid, Chessbase) that allow to make some statistics out of database - but it mostly applies to openings. What I would like is to:
- import my games into the app
- run some kind of analysis (with more or less filters)
- get nicely presented statistical output by category

Sample scenario would be - I put all my standard games from 2016, and I want them to be scanned. After that I get report like:
- 40% lost because of tactical blunders
- 90% of draws were when playing black
- in 20% of won games I've reached endgame

It could be in some way done manually - so I could actually annotate the game with simple tags like: 'pawn endgame', 'slav opening' or 'tactical blunder' and put comments of my own or after I've analysed the game with the coach.

My question is - does this kind of application even exist?

Comment: I haven't heard of such an application, but even if there is one, how do you define a tactical blunder for example? Btw. your second example is a normal use case of a chess database

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

I've built a web tool (https://www.chessinsights.org/) that you can use to upload your games, filter them, and find mistakes you made. The tool is free and open-source.

I'm currently working hard on adding features. If there's something you really want added, just let me know, and I can work on it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of an application that exists, unfortunately.  If there was one, people could probably find out and fix their mistakes far quicker than they do now.

The problem is programming an computer to recognize "tactical blunders" or "positional mistakes".  It's hard to define in logical terms.  Telling a computer to calculate using a point system for pieces and a set of rules is one thing, but teaching it to recognize rather vague concepts is another.

Answer (score 2):

Lichess has something called [chess insights](https://en.lichess.org/blog/VmZbaigAABACtXQC/chess-insights) which looks a lot like what you want. As pointed out by others, you won't get statistics for something like "lost because of tactical blunders" because it is subjective and difficult to assess computationally.

However there are some useful metrics such as *How often you take advantage of your opponent blunders.*